# How to get the intermediate dates given the start date and end date?

Tags: python

```
start_date = '07_Nov_2011'
end_date = '10_Jan_2012'
```

I want to print all the intermediate dates in the same format:

```
day_month_year
```

If I can somehow convert start_date to date type I can do this:

```
sdate+timedelta(1)).strftime('%d_%b_%Y')
```

How do I convert it? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime(...)`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to do the conversion. Like this:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('07_Nov_2011', '%d_%b_%Y').date()
datetime.date(2011, 11, 7)
```

You can print all the intermediate dates with something like this:

```
>>> start_date = '07_Nov_2011'
>>> end_date = '10_Jan_2012'
>>> 
>>> first = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d_%b_%Y')
>>> last = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d_%b_%Y')
>>> for i in xrange((last-first).days):
...     print (first+datetime.timedelta(i)).strftime('%d_%b_%Y')
... 
07_Nov_2011
08_Nov_2011
09_Nov_2011
10_Nov_2011
11_Nov_2011

etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the dates like so:

```
import datetime

start_date = '07_Nov_2007'
end_date = '10_Nov_2007'

startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d_%b_%Y')
endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d_%b_%Y')
oneDay = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

currentDate = startDate
while currentDate <= endDate:
    print currentDate
    currentDate += oneDay
```